# tensor dimension/reshaping group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, tensor

Consider an $N$ dimensional tensor $T$ using the strided view representation used by PyTorch, i.e. we have a storage vector $S$ projected into $N$ dimensions using a size tuple $s$ and a stride tuple $\sigma$ so $T_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}$ is $S_{\sum_{n} i_n  \sigma_n}$.

We support the following operations:

- $\mathit{view}(i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n)$ where $\prod_n{i_n} = \prod_s{s}$, i.e. the size dimensions before multiply to the size dimensions after (the number of elements remains invariant)
- $\mathit{transpose}(T, i, j)$ swaps two dimensions of $T$, $i$ and $j$.

What group defines these operations?

And as a bonus, does the algebra to compute the index into $S$ after repeated operations have an upper bound on complexity that is linear with the complexity of the longest factorization of the number of elements in $T$?